# Utility of loglog plots in curve fitting inverse square relationship

Tags: matlab, plot, dataset, curve-fitting, loglog

I have a a bunch of data that I'd like to use to find an unknown parameter in a physical equation.

I'm trying to find a parameter k to characterise the output of a hall effect sensor as a function on input voltage and distance between the sensor and the magnet. However, I've found this function to be inversely proportional to the square of the distance.

I asked my professor about how to use MATLAB to find the unknown parameter, and he told me I could try to fit it by taking the logarithm of both sides of the equation and plotting that, seen as that would make the relationship linear and thus easier to plot.

I'd have to do this in MATLAB and I'm assuming the values I measured would have to be converted by hand before being able to perform any sort of curve fitting on them.

I was wondering if doing that was worth it, and if there is a faster way of doing this.

Thanks :)

Comment: For calculating the logarithm of your data `x`, you can use `log(x)`. What do you mean with _converted by hand_? It seems that you think it is a time consuming task.

Comment: I thought that maybe I'd have to take all my values and then recalculate them using the logarithmic "transform", and that then I'd be able to fit them linearly. Is there an other way?

Comment: You can try to fit a non linear model directly using [`nlinfit`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html) and a logarithmic model.

Comment: Would it be better than a simple `polyfit`?

Comment: If your the order of your polynomial is high enough, `polyfit` will probably work too as long as you do not try to extrapolate your data. Nevertheless, choosing a good model can you save some time later. For example, it prevents you from overfitting your data and enables you to extrapolate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to easily identify the relationship, for a set input voltage, I had to take the logarithm of the measured distance and the logarithm of the respective output voltages and plot those. Fitting a line through those points then enabled me to see that the coefficient was close enough to -2, confirming the inverse square relationship.

I then did the same for different input voltages and added everything together on the same plot.